# Is it possible to run other doom3 engine based games using the open sourced version of the engine?

Tags: c++, open-source

Other than the doom3 mods, is it possible for example to run Quake 4 or Prey using the game data?

Let's say that I purchase Quake 4 or Prey (or any other idTech 4 game) can I just point to the game data path and run it with the source code? Is there any modification needed? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doubtful.  Almost certainly these games involved some code changes, whether minor or major.  It would be very unusual if Quake 4 or Prey shipped with the *exact* Doom 3 code-base, replacing only the art assets and scripts.  I'd be surprised if the Doom 3 code will run these games correctly.  But since Quake 4 and Prey have not themselves been open-sourced (and may never be), you may be out of luck, unless you feel up to the task of reverse-engineering any code modifications that were made.

Comment: Fairly certain that Quake 4 used Cg shaders whereas Doom 3 used the older assembly language extensions.

Comment: Yeah... I was expecting that to be the case. I guess my question should be, is there any other game that uses the engine without modifications? Probably the answer is also no.